# why get wrong current location in build release apk react native?

Tags: react-native

I don't know why in debug mode current location get correctly but when I build release apk for user test it getting wrong. I use this library => https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geolocation-service

```
// Get current devices location
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
import Permissions, {PERMISSIONS, RESULTS} from 'react-native-permissions';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import Alert from '../src/components/Alert';

function GetCurrentLocation() {
  return new Promise(async resolve => {
    // Check whether user allow location permission or not
    // If user ditn't authorize then do nothing
    const type =
      Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE
        : PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    const permission = await Permissions.request(type);
    if (permission !== RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      return resolve({latitude: null, longitude: null});
    }

    // After user authorized location permission
    // React Native Geolocation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
        resolve({latitude, longitude});
      },
      error => {
        // resolve({latitude: null, longitude: null});
        Alert.alertWithType('warn', 'Location', error.error, 3000);
      },
      {        
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        accuracy: {
          android: 'high',
          ios: 'best',
        },
        timeout: 15000,
        maximumAge: 10000,
        distanceFilter: 10,
      },
    );
  });
}

export default GetCurrentLocation;
```

Comment: can you add some code of how you are getting location?

Comment: help to check it already put my code